# Find keys occurence in list of objects in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to transform this list:

```
list =  [
            {'product_name': '4x6', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
            {'product_name': '4x6', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
            {'product_name': '4x6', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
            {'product_name': '4x6', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
            {'product_name': '4x4', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
            {'product_name': '4x4', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
            {'product_name': '4x4', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
            {'product_name': '4x4', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
        ]
```

into the sum of occurence on the key 'product_name' like this:

```
list_final =  [
            {'product_name': '4x6', 'quantity': 4, 'price': 1.16},
            {'product_name': '4x4', 'quantity': 4, 'price': 1.16},
        ]
```

I can't figure how to search the occurence of the key 'product_name' without doing loops in loops
what I did :

```
for item in list:
    if item.product_name in data.keys():
        data[item.product_name]['qty'] += 1
        data[item.product_name]['price'] *= 2
    else:
        data.update({item.product_name: [{'qty': item['quantity'], 'price': item['price']}]})
```

but I cant find a solution to get my list as I want

how can I do this right ?

Comment: Will your list only have these dicts with the same product name or could the product name vary and you want to sum _every_ separate group (details, details.)?

Comment: yes sorry, the product name can vary and I want the sum of every line by product name

Comment: Please mention that in the question, it's an important detail. Furthermore, please include what you've done to solve this problem.

Comment: You'll need one loop.

Comment: You can use a dictionary where you use the product name as key. All you need is only one explicit loop.

Comment: What if the price per unit changes (inflation or discount?) That information is lost unless you consider it a different product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution with `OrderedDict` that handles multiple products.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

o = OrderedDict()    
for x in data:
    p = x['product_name']
    if p not in o:
        o[p] = x
    else:
        o[p].update({k : o[p][k] + x[k] for k in x.keys() - {'product_name'}})

list_final = list(o.values())
```

A product is added to the inventory if it doesn't exist, or else is summed with the existing inventory. This should work on python3.x and above.

```
print(list_final)
[{'price': 1.16, 'product_name': '4x6', 'quantity': 4}]
```

---

For python2.x, change this

```
o[p].update({k : o[p][k] + x[k] for k in x.keys() - {'product_name'}})
```

To

```
o[p].update({k : o[p][k] + x[k] for k in set(x.keys()) - {'product_name'}})
```

Comment: this is sexy but actually, i'm using python 2.7, could it work on 2.7 ?

Comment: @kidz55 Added in an edit so that it'd work for python2.x. If it helps, don't forget to vote on and accept the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most readable, but here's a for loop-free implementation:

```
def transform(array):
    def inner(cumulator, row):
        product_name = row['product_name']
        bucket = cumulator.get(product_name, {'quantity': 0, 'price': 0})
        cumulator[product_name] = {
            'quantity': bucket['quantity'] + row['quantity'],
            'price': bucket['price'] + row['price'],
        }
        return cumulator
    return reduce(inner, array, {})
```

And then you just

```
transform(list)
// {'4x6': {'price': 1.16, 'quantity': 4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
l =  [
        {'product_name': '4x6', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
        {'product_name': '4x6', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
        {'product_name': '4x6', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
        {'product_name': '4x6', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
        {'product_name': '4x4', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
        {'product_name': '4x4', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
        {'product_name': '4x4', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
        {'product_name': '4x4', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 0.29},
    ]

from collections import defaultdict
count = defaultdict(lambda: {'quantity':0, 'price':0.0})

for d in l:
  count[d['product_name']]['quantity'] += 1
  count[d['product_name']]['price'] = d['price']

for prod_name, prod_info in count.items():
  print("product_name:", prod_name, "quantity: {quantity} price: {price}".format(**prod_info))
```

Output for your input:

```
product_name: 4x6 quantity: 4 price: 0.29
product_name: 4x4 quantity: 4 price: 0.29
```

*Note: This also works with python2*